# Convert a string to a date in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm migrating data between tables in Access 2003.  In the old table, the date was stored as a text field in the format YYYYMMDD.

I want to store the field as a datetime in the new table.  I've tried using `CDate()` in my SQL statement, but it just displays as `#Error` in the results.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

e.g. `cdate(format("20091231", "####/##/##"))`

So, in your case it will be

```
SELECT cdate(format(mystringFieldThatIsInYYYYMMDDFormat, "####/##/##"))   
FROM myData
```