# calling values from database that were inserted between 2 specific dates

Tags: c#, ms-access, select

I want to show the customer accounts for a certain date in my program.

I insert date to my database as string and I want to select record(s) which it's date value is between 2 specific dates. These dates are chosen by user .

I don't know how should I write this line of code . How is the select statement ?

How is changed my code after that?

```
SELECT remined,paidMoney,payment,restOfMoney,factorID FROM tbl_CustomerAccount      where customerName='" + (cmdCustomName.Text) + "' and factorDate????? ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I insert date to my database as string [...] 
>   when i choose from 2013/4/3 to 2013/5/7 ... it gives me (for example)
>   2013/4/4/ ,2013/4/24,2013/5/5, 2013/5/14 ... but I want the 2013/4/3
>   's factors too and also I don't want the 2013/5/14 . what's my wrong ?

What is wrong is that **you are comparing `Strings`, not `Dates`**, and so

2013/5/**1** 4  is before  2013/5/**7** => it is in your query.

In order to compare dates stored as string you need to convert them from string to date, using the `CDate` function. Check this [Convert a string to a date in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397232/convert-a-string-to-a-date-in-access)

The synthax of the accepted answer will work only if the **dates are stored as date**, what is highly recommanded.

Comment: so I changed my input dates from 2013/5/7 to 2013/05/07 .yes it works now :) ... thanks .