# Updating a field dependent on a date range in Access with VisualBasic and SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

A friend and I have been trying for hours with little progress to a get a piece of code right for an invoicing system we're designing as a project.

We are trying to update the field InvoiceNo to a value (worked out earlier in the VisualBasic code), where the CustomerNo is the is a specific value and the FinishDate is between two dates. At first I was trying to use TO_DATE but then we realized that wasn't the same in the SQL that Access uses (after much searching).

This has been the simple statement I've been using to just test and try to get something working to then translate into VisualBasic and put in our variables. It's a little easier to read so I thought I'd provide it.

```
UPDATE tblJob SET tblJob.InvoiceNo = '8' WHERE tblJob.CustomerNo = '1' AND (tblJob.FinishDate BETWEEN cdate(format('08/09/2013', '##/##/####')) AND cdate(format('03/10/2013', '##/##/####')));
```

I have a feeling after looking at a few examples that our date is meant to be without an forward slashes. So I tried that and it wasn't working either.

Here's the VisualBasic code that has come out of all of this, it's exactly the same but using some variables rather than our set values that I've been using for testing.

```
DoCmd.RunSQL ("UPDATE tblJob SET tblJob.InvoiceNo = '" & newInvoiceNo & "' WHERE tblJob.CustomerNo = '" & VbCustNo & "' AND (tblJob.FinishDate BETWEEN cdate(format('" & Forms![frmMainMenu][txtFirstDate] & "', '##/##/####')) AND cdate(format('" & Forms![frmMainmenu][txtEndDate] & "', '##/##/####')));")
```

We had a look at: [Convert a string to a date in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397232/convert-a-string-to-a-date-in-access) and it helped us realize that it was cdate(format()) rather than TO_DATE as it is in Oracle. But we just can't seem to get it to run properly, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: if your dates are in mm/dd/yyyy format you can just use the # character such as BETWEEN #08/09/2013# AND #03/10/2013# Access will see this as a Date

Comment: @engineersmky Thanks, but we're using dd/mm/yyyy though, I'm guessing it's not going to work in the same way?

Comment: you can always use `DateSerial` which is `DateSerial(Year,Month,Day)` So like `DateSerial(Right([YourDate],4),Mid([YourDate],3,2),Left([YourDate],2)`. this will return a date object in the correct format. This is how I handle properly formatted string dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will be running the query from within an Access application session, you can let the db engine use the Access expression service to grab the values from the text boxes on your form.

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim strUpdate As String
strUpdate = "UPDATE tblJob" & vbCrLf & _
    "SET InvoiceNo = '" & newInvoiceNo & "'" & vbCrLf & _
    "WHERE CustomerNo = '" & VbCustNo & "'" & vbCrLf & _
    "AND FinishDate BETWEEN Forms!frmMainMenu!txtFirstDate AND Forms!frmMainmenu!txtEndDate;"
Debug.Print strUpdate
Set db = CurrentDb
db.Execute strUpdate, dbFailOnError
Set db = Nothing
```

However, if you prefer to build the literal date values from those text boxes into your `UPDATE` statement, you can use `Format()`.

```vb
"AND FinishDate BETWEEN " & _
Format(Forms!frmMainmenu!txtFirstDate, "\#yyyy-m-d\#") & _
" AND " & Format(Forms!frmMainmenu!txtEndDate, "\#yyyy-m-d\#") & ";"
```

Either way, using a string variable to hold your `UPDATE` statement gives you an opportunity to examine the completed statement you're asking the db engine to execute.

You can view the output from `Debug.Print` in the Immediate window (go there with <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>).  For troubleshooting, you can copy the statement text from there and then paste it into SQL View of a new Access query.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I put in your first set of code and it didn't run correctly and spat out the error "Run-time error '3464': Data type mismatch in criteria expression." which is the same as we kept getting.

I've then attempted your second solution, and we got the same error.

Comment: What are the data types of the `InvoiceNo`, `CustomerNo`, and `FinishDate` fields?  Based on the example in your question, I presumed they are text, text and Date/Time respectively.

Comment: When you copy the `Debug.Print` output and paste it into SQL View of a new query in the Access query designer, can you then identify the changes needed to avoid that error?