# From String to Date Store in Access 2013

Tags: java, sql, date, ms-access

Suppose we have a string "11/12/1990"
I need to store it in Access 2013 where I have put the field Data Type as Date/Time and the format is dd/mm/yyyy.
The DB connections are working well
I need the SQL, and if any adjustement needs to be made or any further functions need to be used

Language used: JAVA

Comment: Show us some effort, what did you try?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397232/convert-a-string-to-a-date-in-access

Comment: You need either a date value or - if concatenating SQL code - a string expression of the date value like #1990/12/11#. Which depends on your code.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should serve as an example:

```java
package ucanaccesstest;

import java.sql.*;

public class UCanAccessTestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dbFileSpec = "C:/Users/Public/mdbTest.mdb";
        String connStr = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + dbFileSpec;
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connStr)) {
            try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
                    "UPDATE Members SET DateJoined=? WHERE MemberID=1")) {
                java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                // the next line
                //   - parses a "dd/mm/yyyy" date string into a java.util.Date object,
                //   - converts that into a java.sql.Timestamp object, and then
                //   - sets the value of the first (and only) query parameter
                ps.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(sdf.parse("11/12/1990").getTime()));
                ps.executeUpdate();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }

}
```